# Internal Error: Blackberry 9800 Simulator

Tags: java-me, eclipse-plugin, simulator, blackberry-simulator

I am new to Blackberry development. I downloaded and installed Eclipse plugin for Blackberry v1.5. It was successful but everything I try to run a sample code that is running on my friend's machine i get this error.

Internal Error: Blackberry 9800 Simulator
Access violation reading from 0x0000013C

Please what is the cause and solution of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time try searching "Internal Error: Blackberry 9800 Simulator Access violation reading from 0x0000013C"

Solutions [here](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/94512-strange-new-error.html),
[here](http://www.blackberrysoftware.us/n10175,blackberry-simulator-application-error-problem-fix.html) ,
[here](http://www.programmingodyssey.com/2011/03/solution-for-device-error-blackberry.html) ,
and [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/what-is-this-device-simulator-error/td-p/38322)

Comment: thanks! [this solution](http://www.programmingodyssey.com/2011/03/solution-for-device-error-blackberry.html) did the trick!